# Adding additional option to default Android's application

Tags: android

Is it possible adding additional option to system's default alarm that may trigger my App's function whenever the alarm rings? This is MIUI 6's Alarm and possibly applying it to all Android's?

[image: MIUI 6's default Alarm system]

Comment: you need to know what is broadcast name when the alarm ringing. and in your app just make broadcast receiver that listen to its broadcast name

Answer (score 0):

An option that would apply to all androids will be to set a `BroadcastReceiver` to your app, so that it listens to various events. Check this [link](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/10/alarm-example-in-android.html?m=1) where the whole process is described

Edit: link fixed

Comment: The link provided "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist."
Thanks in advance.. Getting brief idea about it

Comment: Oh got it now.. you double pasted the link's url